# Как получать settings конфигурацию в отдельный класс в net core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6

У меня есть класс ConnectionSettings с помощью которого я хочу получить connectionString из appsettings.json

```
    public class ConnectionSettings
    {
        public string UserDataServiceDbConnection { get; set; }
    }
```

Мне он нужен, чтобы передать строку подключения в класс BaseRepository

```
     public class BaseRepository
    {
        private readonly ConnectionSettings _settings;
        public BaseRepository(IOptionsSnapshot<ConnectionSettings> settings) 
        {
            _settings = settings.Value;
        }

        public List<T> Query<T>(string query, object parameters = null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new 
 NpgsqlConnection(_settings.UserDataServiceDbConnection))
                {
                    return conn.Query<T>(query, parameters).ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new List<T>();
            }
        }
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как правильно передать конфигурацию в net core 6
Часть кода из Program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<ConnectionSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:UserDataServiceDbConnection"));
```

В итоге вместо строки подключения я получаю null. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `ConnectionSettings` и `IOptionsSnapshot<ConnectionSettings>` замените на `IConfiguration`; `_settings = settings.Value` замените на `_settings = settings;`. Ну и дальше, получение настроек простым `_settings["UserDataServiceDbConnection"]`.

Comment: Не помогло, может надо что-то в Program прописать, чтобы в IConfiguration попали данные?

Comment: Я немного невнимательно посмотрел ваш код, а вы даже не заметили... У вас же  `ConnectionStrings:UserDataServiceDbConnection`, а не просто `UserDataServiceDbConnection`, вот это и пишите. По поводу "надо прописать?" - по умолчанию у вас уже должно в проекте все быть прописанным, а настройки должны быть в `appsettings.json`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!